# ¿Forma correcta de mostrar los datos en un servicio web con spring boot?

Tags: java, json, webservice, spring-boot

quisiera saber cual es la forma "correcta" de dar los resultados en un servicio web con spring boot. Por ejemplo una posibilidad de devolver los datos en JSON (la cual yo usaba) es:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Nuevas Alegrías",
    "cantante": {
        "id": 1,
        "nombreCantante": "Jose Feliciano",
        "edad": "20",
        "numeroDiscos": "4"
}
```

En la cual hay dos entidades Canción y Cantante, habiendo una relación bi-direccional entre estas dos entidades ya que un cantante tienes varias canciones y una cancion tiene un solo cantante. Al consultar un endpoint para obtener una canción con sus datos me arroja el código que esta arriba,y en esa repuesta esta toda la información del cantante que le corresponde esa canción.

Pero también me di cuenta que otros programadores exponen los datos de su servicio de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Nuevas Alegrías",
    "id_cantante": 1
}
```

En la cual me arroja los datos de la canción consultada pero no me da todo la información del cantante sino solo su id y supongo que con este id del cantante se haría otra consulta si es necesario para obtener su información.

Quisiera saber cual es mejor o peor y viendo la segunda consulta creo que se tendrían que hacer dos llamadas al backend para conseguir la información que arrojaba la primera forma de respuesta del servicio. ¿Esto traería algún problema de rendimiento o algo parecido?

Comment: Particularmente , he visto en distintas aplicaciones la segunda implementacion , creo , y es a opinion personal que se usa para generalizar las peticiones y reducir las que tienes que realizar , me explico : Si , haces dos peticiones al back , pero si el dia de mañana tienes otra clase como "album" que tambien tiene cantante , solo tendrias que preocuparte de hacer la parte de album , garantizandote que la parte de "Cantante" ya esta implementada ( y lo que ello conlleva en test , codigo ... )

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan siendo cerradas. Te sugiero que ajustes tu pregunta para que se enfoque en un problema de programación.